# position absolute within position relative not working correctly

Tags: css, css-position

Ok so I'm aligning these two boxes to the bottom of the outer div by making the outer div position relative and the two inner boxes position absolute.

Here is a fiddle of the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/QEr8L/

```
<div id="graph-top-bar" class="clearfix">
        <section class="brand clearfix">
            <img src="images/calc-brand-img.png" alt="" class="hidden-sm">
            <div class="content">
                <h1 class="brand-title">Brand R Bag</h1>
                <h4>Inverted Marking Paint</h4>
                <select id="brand" name="brand">
                    <option value="Brand R Bag" data-value="r-bag">BRAND R BAG</option>
                    <option value="Brand R Aerosol" data-value="r">BRAND R AEROSOL</option>
                    <option value="Brand A Aerosol" data-value="a">BRAND A AEROSOL</option>
                    <option value="Brand S Aerosol" data-value="s">BRAND S AEROSOL</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="hidden-sm vs">
            <img src="images/calc-vs.png" alt="VS">
        </section>
        <section class="krylon clearfix">
            <div class="content">
                <h1 class="krylon-title">Krylon Industrial 17oz</h1>
                <h4>Inverted Marking Paint</h4>
                <select id="krylon" name="krylon">
                    <option value="Krylon Industrial 17oz" data-value="17">17oz</option>
                    <option value="Krylon Industrial 22oz" data-value="22">22oz</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <img src="images/calc-krylon-img.png" alt="" class="hidden-sm">
        </section>
    </div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#graph-top-bar {
    background: #474747;
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJod…EiIGhlaWdodD0iMSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkKSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #474747 0%, #000000 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#474747), color-stop(100%,#000000));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #474747 0%,#000000 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #474747 0%,#000000 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #474747 0%,#000000 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #474747 0%,#000000 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#474747', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=0 );
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
#graph-top-bar .brand {
    width: 48%;
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    bottom: 20px;
}
.hidden-sm {
    display: none;
}
#graph-top-bar h1 {
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 150%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
#graph-top-bar h4 {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 80%;
    margin-top: -5px;
}
#graph-top-bar select {
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #ffffff;
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJod…EiIGhlaWdodD0iMSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkKSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #959595 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#959595));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#959595 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#959595 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#959595 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%,#959595 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#959595',GradientType=0 );
    border: 1px solid #000;
    font-size: 80%;
    padding: 6px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#graph-top-bar .krylon {
    width: 48%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: right;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 20px;
}
#graph-top-bar .krylon {
    text-align: right;
}


select {
    width: 100%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 7px #8c8c8c;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 7px #8c8c8c;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 7px #8c8c8c;
    border: 1px solid #b3b3b3;
    background: #fff;
    color: #3b3b3b;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 35px;
    text-indent: 15px;
    line-height: 29px;
}


.clearfix:after {
     visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     font-size: 0;
     content: " ";
     clear: both;
     height: 0;
}
.clearfix { display: inline-block; }
/* start commented backslash hack \*/
* html .clearfix { height: 1%; }
.clearfix { display: block; }
/* close commented backslash hack */
```

It's suppose to look like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/4cKy2/

But I need it positioned to the bottom for when the h1 tag starts to wrap on two lines and the other one doesn't.. it starts getting jagged. You can see it when you minimize your browser.

Thanks for any help on this. I don't see why the text keeps going off the black background and the black background won't wrap around it..

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It's working as supposed. You position it 20px to the bottom. It goes over the top of the parent only because the parent is too small. Set a higher height to the parent or fill it with some content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position absolute means : **absolute coordinates to its parent**, *without consideration of wrapping, going off the black background or whatever*. **As absolute positioning pulls the elements out of the HTML flow** : your black box behaves like it has no content.

In your case, the to big inputs are 20px to the bottom of the black box, that's what you told it to do.

You have to stylise the black box (*make it bigger, fill with some content*), and you will see the two inputs staying 20px to the bottom.

Comment: Hmm ok. Thank you. So I kind of have no choice but to give it a defined min-height? The parent div? Because that's the only content in it.

Comment: yes that's it: but absolute positioning seems useless in this case.

Comment: How so? If you minimize the browser, you can see it becoming jagged.. Because the header of one will drop on two lines while the other doesn't so the box will become longer and uneven.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set height for the `div#graph-top-bar`

```
#graph-top-bar {
    height: 170px;  /* your height */
```

position `absolute` elements don't take up space.

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QEr8L/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

you have too much css... what are you trying to accomplish with absolute position? I think you wanted the following...

```
#graph-top-bar {
                background: #474747;
                background: url(                data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJod…EiIGhlaWdodD0iMSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkKSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+);
                background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #474747 0%, #000000 100%);
                background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#474747), color-stop(100%,#000000));
                background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #474747 0%,#000000 100%);
                background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #474747 0%,#000000 100%);
                background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #474747 0%,#000000 100%);
                background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #474747 0%,#000000 100%);
                filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#474747', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=0 );
                padding: 40px;
            }

            #graph-top-bar .brand {
                width: 48%;
                float: left;
            }

            .hidden-sm {
            }

            #graph-top-bar h1 {
                font-style: italic;
                font-size: 150%;
                word-wrap: break-word;
            }
            #graph-top-bar h4 {
                font-weight: normal;
                font-size: 80%;
                margin-top: -5px;
            }
            #graph-top-bar select {
                margin: 0;
                -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
                -moz-border-radius: 4px;
                border-radius: 4px;
                background: #ffffff;
                background: url(                data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJod…EiIGhlaWdodD0iMSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkKSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+);
                background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #959595 100%);
                background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#959595));
                background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#959595 100%);
                background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#959595 100%);
                background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#959595 100%);
                background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%,#959595 100%);
                filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#959595',GradientType=0 );
                border: 1px solid #000;
                font-size: 80%;
                padding: 6px;
                font-weight: bold;
            }

            #graph-top-bar .krylon {
            width: 48%;
            text-align: right;
            float: right;
            }


            select {
                width: 100%;
                -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 7px #8c8c8c;
                -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 7px #8c8c8c;
                box-shadow: inset 0 0 7px #8c8c8c;
                border: 1px solid #b3b3b3;
                background: #fff;
                color: #3b3b3b;
                display: inline-block;
                height: 35px;
                text-indent: 15px;
                line-height: 29px;
            }


            .clearfix:after {
                 visibility: hidden;
                 display: block;
                 font-size: 0;
                 content: " ";
                 clear: both;
                 height: 0;
            }
            .clearfix { display: inline-block; }
            /* start commented backslash hack \*/
            * html .clearfix { height: 1%; }
            .clearfix { display: block; }
            /* close commented backslash hack */
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QEr8L/1/

Comment: Minimize your browser.. you can see the two divs inside the parent become jagged so that's why I was aligning them to the very bottom so they don't do that.

Comment: I always try to avoid absolute... The way I have it your container    id="graph-top-bar" takes the shape of its content and allows you to change the content without having to change the h&w...If you are worried about the jagged edge there are many solves like @media or bootstrap or even elipse the overflow.

Answer (score -3):

You should set height on #graph-top-bar;

```
#graph-top-bar {
    height: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Regardless of your reputation, you shouldn't do this.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).